# Sliding Arrow Under Active Menu Tab

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

Here is the picture for your reference.

[image]

I want to move my arrow slide over active menu.For example onclick of menu paused that top arrow should move from active to paused similarly for every menu `onclick` it slide over.By default arrow should point active menu.This set Of menu should be like tab set so that onclick of active menu.List of items should be display inside tabset div.Similarly for all Menus.For this i tried below code But i can't achieve the task.

**Code Snippet:**

```css
.db-new-filters {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.db-new-filters .tabs {
  border-bottom: 1px #dddddd solid;
  position: relative;
}
ul,
ol,
nav ul,
nav ol {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-image: none;
}
.db-new-filters .tabs li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.db-new-filters .tabs li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 11px;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: left 0.3s;
  -o-transition: left 0.3s;
  transition: left 0.3s;
}
.db-new-filters .tabs li a {
  padding: 3px 5px 10px 5px;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 42px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.db-new-filters .tabs li.pointer {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #dddddd;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="db-new-filters">
  <ul class="tabs js-db-status-tabs">
    <li><a>Active</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Paused</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Pending</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Unapproved</a>
    </li>
    <li class="pointer" style="left: 193.5px;"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And i tried google in many ways But i can't find the solution.If anybody knows the solution let me know the solution.I wasted more than hour to solve this problem.If anyone help me that is grateful for my work.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code.

**Html code :**

```
<div class="services-block">
  <div id="services-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner services" role="listbox" >
      <div class="item active" id="services">
        <ul class="tabbed-menu menu-list">
          <li><a href="javascript:rudrSwitchTab('tb_1', 'content_1');" id="tb_1" class="tabmenu active">Menu nav 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:rudrSwitchTab('tb_2', 'content_2');" id="tb_2" class="tabmenu">Menu navigation 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:rudrSwitchTab('tb_3', 'content_3');" id="tb_3" class="tabmenu">Menu navigation 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:rudrSwitchTab('tb_4', 'content_4');" id="tb_4" class="tabmenu">Menu nav 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:rudrSwitchTab('tb_5', 'content_5');" id="tb_5" class="tabmenu">Menu navigation 5</a></li>
          <li><a class="right carousel-control" href="#services-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">Menu nav 6</a></li>
       </ul>                 
     </div> <!--/.item active-->

   </div> <!--/.carousel-inner-->
   <div id="marker"></div>
 </div> <!--/#services-carousel-->
</div> <!--services-block-->
```

**Css code :**

```
#services-carousel, #services {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
ul {
  overflow:hidden;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;  
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#marker {
background: transparent url("http://cdn7.unit4.com/images/theme/2014/icons/down.png") no-repeat scroll 50% 50%;   
height: 16px;
left: 4%;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
width: 45px;
transition: .4s left ease-in;
}
```

**Javascript code :**

```
 $("#services ul > li").click(function(event){
    var position = $(this).position().left;
    var width = Math.round($(this).width()/2) - 5;
    var arrowPos = position + width;
    $('#marker').css('left', arrowPos);
    event.preventDefault();
  });
```

for more detail visit this : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vObmJV

Comment: arrow should slide on line..And moreover it is towards down

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with help of `jQuery`. I have modified your HTML and CSS using `:after` pseudo element.

**Check below example:**

```js
$(function() {
  $('ul.tabs a').click(function() {
    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.db-new-filters {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.db-new-filters .tabs {
  border-bottom: 1px #dddddd solid;
  position: relative;
}
ul,
ol,
nav ul,
nav ol {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-image: none;
}
.db-new-filters .tabs li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.db-new-filters .tabs li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 11px;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: left 0.3s;
  -o-transition: left 0.3s;
  transition: left 0.3s;
}
.db-new-filters .tabs li a {
  padding: 3px 5px 10px 5px;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 42px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.db-new-filters .tabs li.active::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  left: calc(50% - 10px);
  border-bottom: 10px solid #dddddd;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="db-new-filters">
  <ul class="tabs js-db-status-tabs">
    <li class="active">
      <a>Active</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Paused</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Pending</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Unapproved</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this code but arrow is not in correct position.it is showing above menu.

Comment: Have you added `position: relative;` this to `.db-new-filters .tabs li` ?

Comment: Ya i added @Pugazh